# Why my nodejs REST API doesn't work on HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have droplet on digital ocean. I use nginx as reverse proxy for my REST API in nodeJS

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:/var/www/html/app# curl -v -k  https://0.0.0.0:8080/api/posts
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I still have this error and I am not able to solve it (CURL just on HTTP give me expected JSON as a result, so it's ok).

This is my config

```
index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name premonstrati2021.cz www.premonstrati2021.cz;

        location / {
            proxy_pass                    https://0.0.0.0:8080;

            proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted_ca_cert.crt;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_ssl_verify        on;
            proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
        }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;

        root /var/www/html/app/dist;

        server_name  premonstrati2021.cz www.premonstrati2021.cz;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem
        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/cert.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/premonstrati2021.cz/privkey.pem";
        ssl_verify_client      optional;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
             ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES2$

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
}
```

Log from PM2 is clear, there is no problem.

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong with your SSL/TLS settings, you'd better ask this question at serverfault.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3\_get\_record:wrong version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number)

Comment: Looking closer, why are you trying to use https on port 8080? It is the port where your nodejs app is listening, try `curl -v -k  https://0.0.0.0/api/posts` instead.

Comment: I tried ports 3000, 8443 and like last option 8080. Yes it is port of my nodejs app. It is strange - now I try `curl -v -k  https://0.0.0.0/api/posts` and I get 404 (`curl -v -k  https://0.0.0.0` is found like my homepage - so it well).

For more info: my app is based on Nuxt.js

Comment: @MartinZeitler i dont think it is my case because I dont use this var in config how you can see. or how can test if i use this variable? I am novice in nginx, ssl and these things. So thanks for patience.

Comment: I found that problem could be SSL3 so I used this in config 
`ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky ok I move the discussion here https://serverfault.com/questions/1023451/why-my-nodejs-rest-api-doesnt-work-on-https thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it - I haven't prepare my nodejs app on https :-(.

It was listening just on http.