# Can I transfer SSL traffic from one server to another?

Tags: php, ssl, tcp

I have a PHP script which starts a socks5 server. Also I have PHP script on another server which connects to that socks5 server and waits for requests. As soon as request from socks5 server received I want to transfer the traffic to second server and make HTTPS request to WEB. It works on with HTTP, but with HTTPS for examples curls gives the errors:

> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: [www.one.lt](http://www.one.lt)
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*

- TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, protocol version (582):
- OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number, errno 0
- Failed receiving HTTP2 data
- OpenSSL SSL_write: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
- Failed sending HTTP2 data
- Connection #0 to host [www.one.lt](http://www.one.lt) left intact
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number, errno 0

How to fix that?

Comment: A socks5 proxy does not infer with the traffic, it just forwards it. This is true for both HTTP and HTTPS. Which means there is likely something wrong with the way you setup or use the proxy - both of these is unknown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3\_get\_record:wrong version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number)

Comment: No, it's not, @Naktibalda