# Getting SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am running an Nginx reverse proxy but when I am doing a curl I am getting error while running
curl https://test-website.com:444
"SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number".
Here is my default.conf

```
listen 444 ssl;
server_name test-website.com;

# Path for SSL config/key/certificate
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/site1.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/site1.key;
include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;

location / {
include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
proxy_pass https://IdentityApi:5501;
}

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}

# Default
server {
listen 80 default_server;

server_name _;
root /var/www/html;

charset UTF-8;

error_page 404 /backend-not-found.html;
location = /backend-not-found.html {
allow   all;
}
location / {
return 404;
}

access_log off;
log_not_found off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

ssl.conf

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

proxy.conf

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

Is there any issue with the conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue helped me with the same error but a different circumstance:
[curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number)

Had to change from https to HTTP

While I don't think this solves your question, maybe thinking about where there could be a different protocol in your file might help.