# Failed to call bootstrap-vcpkg.sh on WSL2 (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: vcpkg

This is what I have tried to do and results so far:

```
user@machine:~$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
Cloning into 'vcpkg'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 118393, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (96/96), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Total 118393 (delta 82), reused 74 (delta 74), pack-reused 118297
Receiving objects: 100% (118393/118393), 38.01 MiB | 1.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (73672/73672), done.
```

```
user@machine:~$ cd vcpkg
user@machine:~/vcpkg$ ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
Downloading cmake...
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

So I have the wrong version of OpenSSL or what is the problem here?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue...

The problem was that the proxy was not setup properly. The solution was posted here by Sachit Yadav here:

[curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number/50842202)

I needed to add a ~/.curlrc file with the following line:

proxy="http://ip_to_proxy:proxy_port_nr"

After this the bootstrapping script worked.