# extract_tables function status was 'SSL connect error' error

Tags: ssl, tabulizer

I posed a similar question in [Github](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/141). However, as I could not receive reply, I just wanted to post it here in case someone can help me on this issue. Thank you for your help beforehand.

During the last two days, I am trying to install tabulizer package so that I can retrieve some information from an online pdf and conduct some analysis on this data. I managed to upload the package in my R Studio, however when I run this line of code

```
library(tabulizer)  
library(tabulizerjars)
library(dplyr)

url <- "http://www.sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf"
out <- extract_tables(url)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in utils::download.file(path, tmp, quiet = quiet, mode = "wb") : 
  URL 'http://www.sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf' açılamıyor
Ek olarak: Warning message:
In utils::download.file(path, tmp, quiet = quiet, mode = "wb") :
  URL 'https://sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf': status was 'SSL connect error'
```

To solve this problem, I have tried a couple of solutions. [Based on this solution at the Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840101/curl-35-error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number), I deleted "s" from http but the error still says "https" which I could not understand.

To check whether this situation is unique to this website, I also tried a similar attempt in another website by the following code;

To check whether this situation is unique to this website, I also tried a similar attempt in another website by the following code;

```
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS"
out <- extract_tables(url)
```

At this time, I received this error;

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo
```

When I looked at some solutions, I saw this [this one](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/42). The solutions at this link mostly were about the previous versions of Java as far as I understood. However, I recently dowloaded Java on my Mac and its version is

`java version "1.8.0_311"`

Based on the solution in [this link](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/42), I also run the following code

```
.jinit()
.jcall("java/lang/System", "S", "getProperty", "java.runtime.version")
```

which game me this result

```
"1.8.0_311-b11"
```

Therefore, I do not think my problem is occurring due to previous versions of Java. I also attached my session Information. If you help me on this issue I will be really glad for that. Thank you in advance.

## Here is my session info

```
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
 os       macOS 12.0.1                
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  tr_TR.UTF-8                 
 ctype    tr_TR.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Istanbul             
 date     2021-11-20                  

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package       * version date       lib source                                 
 askpass         1.1     2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 cachem          1.0.5   2021-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 callr           3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 cellranger      1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 cli             3.0.1   2021-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 crayon          1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 curl          * 4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 DBI             1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 desc            1.3.0   2021-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 devtools      * 2.4.2   2021-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 digest          0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 dplyr         * 1.0.7   2021-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 evaluate        0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 fansi           0.5.0   2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 fs              1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 generics        0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 glue            1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 htmltools       0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 knitr           1.33    2021-04-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 lifecycle       1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 magrittr        2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 memoise         2.0.0   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 pdftools      * 3.0.1   2021-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 pillar          1.6.2   2021-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 pkgbuild        1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 pkgload         1.2.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 png             0.1-7   2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 prettyunits     1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 processx        3.5.2   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 ps              1.6.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 purrr           0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 qpdf            1.1     2019-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 R6              2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 Rcpp            1.0.7   2021-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 readxl          1.3.1   2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 remotes       * 2.4.1   2021-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rJava         * 1.0-5   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rlang           0.4.11  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rmarkdown       2.9     2021-06-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rprojroot       2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rsconnect       0.8.24  2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 rstudioapi      0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 sessioninfo     1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 tabulizer     * 0.2.2   2021-11-20 [1] Github (ropensci/tabulizer@9f45f91)    
 tabulizerjars * 1.0.1   2021-11-20 [1] Github (ropensci/tabulizerjars@d1924e0)
 testthat        3.0.4   2021-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 tibble          3.1.3   2021-07-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 tidyselect      1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 usethis       * 2.0.1   2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 utf8            1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 vctrs           0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 withr           2.4.2   2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 writexl         1.4.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 xfun            0.25    2021-08-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)                         
 yaml            2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Actually, I am trying to extract data from an online pdf document to use for my project. To this end, I thought tabulizer package is best and I tried to use it but I could not. Regarding your comment, I could not understand how to run this line of code: `curl -o mynext.pdf http://www.sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf` Apologize for my ignorance but I do not think it can be run on R Studio right? If you can a bit elaborate on your comment, I really appreciate this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Right now, I am using Mac. In line with your suggestion, I actually tried to install `curl`in R Studio and then run this code, just to see what will happen; `req <- curl_fetch_memory("https://www.sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf")` I received the following error:
 `Error in curl_fetch_memory("https://www.sbb.gov.tr/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/KonutPolitikalariOzelIhtisasKomisyonuRaporu.pdf") : 
  error:06FFF089:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad key length`,

Comment: when I searched solution it was written that it might be related to MacOS but I am not sure.